# (Swift) status bar appearance UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, I present a UIImagePickerController. The problem is that when I present the ImagePickerController the statut bar become black. Do you know how I can fix that (Swift) ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't adding

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent`

this code to your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in AppDelagate work?

Comment: how about adding `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)` this code to viewDidLoad function in your every controller class?